# Как скомпилировать файл main.cpp через консоль в apk?

Tags: android, c++, terminal

Можно подробное описание для понятия как это работает, типо что где нужно прописывать, какие файлы создавать. Можно максимально топорно прям через блокнот и консоль. Я знаю высказывания по поводу того что это тупо и и так делать не стоит. Но я просто хочу понять как это работает. Если можно то поясните пожалуйста как потом привязать к этому всему библиотеку(SDL) и тоже собрать под андроид.

Comment: Очень долго расписывать но вам надо сюда: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build потом сюда https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/ и еще https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager и еще https://habr.com/post/309504/

Comment: Я все-таки скажу. С SDL2 уже идет в комплекте готовый проект для андроида. Не уверен, что без него она вообще будет работать, т.к. когда я в последний туда заглядывал, там было много всяких наворотов.